# NodeJS - child_process spawn used with python interactive shell - no visible output

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm working on a (rather stupid) script. One of the things it needs to be able to do is, given python code, execute it. It also needs to be interactive. After a decent amount of looking around, I decided to use child_process spawning. However, the output doesn't seem to be showing up when I try it.

Take this for example:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var p = spawn('python3',['-q']);

p.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    if (data.toString() != '>>> ') {
        console.log(data.toString());
    }
});

p.stdin.write("print('hello world')\n");
```

The thing I'm trying to do here should be pretty obvious. The behavior I'm looking for is for the phrase "hello world" to appear in the console. However, nothing appears. child_process exec seems to work, but like I said, I need this to be interactive, and exec doesn't seem to be able to do that, as all output appears at the end rather than as a stream. Help?

Answer (score 0):

So the easiest way to make it interactive to make the `stdio` option to inherit. I have never found a complete solution as these interactive processes are running and the `childProcess.stdout` and `childProcess.stdin` only pipes the OUTPUT of that program. For a interactive shell like python it doesn't output anything, it exits with a return code `0`.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('python3', ['-q'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
```

But for the `p.stdout.on` to work you need to spawn it like this:
`spawn('python','-c','print("hello world");')` and you can see the output `hello world`

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const p = spawn('python3', ['-c','print("hello world");']);

p.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
   console.log(data.toString());
});
```

You can use this with `readline` for emulated interactiveness.

Comment: That's unfortunate. That's exactly what I was trying to avoid: I really need the interactive shell so your second answer isn't really quite it, but the first one would be fine if I didn't also need to use stdio for different stuff... maybe I can try starting with the first one and see if I can find a workaround. For such a simple task, there really ought to be some sort of implementation. *sigh*

Comment: I am very interested in a solution to this problem. Did you manage to find a solution ?